# Using maps in Scala

Tags: scala, match, head, tail

```
val nums = Map('M' -> 1000, 'D' -> 500, 'C' -> 100, 'L' -> 50, 'X' -> 10, 'V' -> 5, 'I' -> 1)
def convert(data : String):Int = {
    var count = 0;
    var index = 0;
    var list: List[Char] = List();

    for((value,index) <- data.reverse.zipWithIndex){
        list = value :: list;
    }

    def calcRM(rm : List[Char]): List[Char] = rm match{
        case x :: Nil => x
        case x :: tail => ???
        case Nil => Nil
    }

    return count        
    }
}
```

I am wondering how I can convert the value I get from `x(head)` and `tail.head` by using the `Map` provided so I can convert the string to the value in Roman Numerals.

Answer (score 3):

To access a map, you simply use its `get` method:

```
nums.get(x)
```

which returns an `Option` that you would have to unwrap, so you can assume all good values and use the `apply`:

```
nums(x) //Throws if key not found
```

or you could use a default:

```
nums.getOrElse(x, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `apply` method on `Map`.  Recall that you can call `apply` simply by adding parentheses:

```
nums('M') //returns 1000
nums.apply('M') //equivalent in Scala
```

You can also use `get` to return an `Option[Int]` if you aren't sure the key is available in the `Map`, and you want to avoid the exception that would otherwise be thrown by apply:

```
nums.get('M') //returns Some(1000)
nums.get('K') //returns None
nums('K') //throws an exception
```

I would also recommend looking into some of the more idiomatic paradigms  in Scala (e.g. using `val`).  For your example, you might consider something like this, which uses inner methods and values, slightly more complex pattern matching, the ever important `map` method, the implicit `apply` used in the map, and recursion:

```
def convert(rm: String) = {
    val nums = Map('M' -> 1000, 'D' -> 500, 'C' -> 100, 'L' -> 50, 'X' -> 10, 'V' -> 5, 'I' -> 1)
    def calcRM(rm: Seq[Int]): Int = rm match {
        case x :: y :: tail if x < y => y - x + calcRM(tail)
        case x :: tail => x + calcRM(tail)
        case Nil => 0
    }
    calcRM(rm.map(nums).toList)
}
```